Getting cloud_firestore/permission-denied and don't understand why
In my Flutter app I am reading data from a document in the Cloud Firestore as this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:tidsrapport/homewidgets/error_widget.dart';
import 'package:tidsrapport/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:tidsrapport/homewidgets/home_portraitview.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import '../database/database.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

class StampInFromOffice extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
const StampInFromOffice({super.key});

@override
ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() {
  // TODO: implement createState
  return _StampInFromOfficeState();
}
}

class _StampInFromOfficeState extends ConsumerState<StampInFromOffice> {
late bool connectedToWifi;
late String information;
late double width;
late double height;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

Widget _createLayout() {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: HomeTemplate(
      screenHeight: height,
      screenWidth: width,
      child: _createStampInFromOfficeWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _createStampInFromOfficeWidget() {
  final userDocumentStream = ref.watch(userStreamProvider);
  return userDocumentStream.when(
    data: (data) {
      try {
        bool signedIn = data['Signed In'];
        bool workingRemotely = data['Working Remotely'];
        return _stampedInOrOutTile(signedIn, workingRemotely);
      } catch (error) {
        return const ErrorText(errorText: 'Couldn\'t retrieve data');
      }
    },
    error: (error, stack) {
      developer.log('Error: $error');
      return const ErrorText(errorText: 'Couldn\'t retrieve data');
    },
    loading: () {
      return const Loading();
    },
  );
}

Widget _stampedInOrOutTile(bool atOffice, bool atHome) {
  LinearGradient theme;
  String buttonText;
  if (atOffice) {
    theme = LinearGradient(colors: [
      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
    ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter);
    atHome == true ? buttonText = 'At Home' : buttonText = 'At Office';
  } else {
    theme = const LinearGradient(colors: [
      Colors.red,
      Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 32, 19),
    ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter);
    buttonText = 'Signed Out';
  }
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment:
        MainAxisAlignment.center, //Center Column contents vertically,
    crossAxisAlignment:
        CrossAxisAlignment.center, //Center Column contents horizontally,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: (width / 1.5),
        height: (height / 16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: theme,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Workmanager().cancelAll();
            String now = DateFormat.yMd().format(
              DateTime.now(),
            );
            await Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
              'new-task',
              'automaticBackgroundTask',
              inputData: {'string': 'Started At $now'},
            );
          },
          child: Text(buttonText),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   height = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
   width = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
   Widget screenWidget = _createLayout();
   return screenWidget;
 }
}

I am reading data from a user document, the rules for which I've defined like this
match /users/{userID} {
    allow write, read: if request.auth != null && userID== request.auth.uid;
}

When I log in to the app for the first time, I am able to retrieve the data with no issue, but if I log out, then log in again, I recieve the error

[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

However when I turn off my app, and then turn it on again I'm able to retrieve the data without any error again whatsoever.
I don't understand why I the permission handling rules works correctly when I first login, starts working when I re-login and it starts working correctly again after

buddy Check Authentication State Before Reading
userDocumentStream.when(
  data: (data) {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      try {
        bool signedIn = data['Signed In'];
        bool workingRemotely = data['Working Remotely'];
        return _stampedInOrOutTile(signedIn, workingRemotely);
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
      }
    } else {
      // User not authenticated, show loading or handle state
    }
    return Container(); // or appropriate widget
  },
  // ... other cases
);

and also handle authentication satate changes something like this
StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const ErrorText(errorText: 'Error fetching data');
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final user = snapshot.data;
      if (user != null) {
        // User is signed in, fetch data
        return _createStampInFromOfficeWidget();
      } else {
        // User is signed out, show appropriate UI
        return const Text('Please sign in to access data');
      }
    }

    return const Loading();
  },
);

let me know if it helps to diagnose

Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. I changed the build method to a stream builder which listens to auth state changes, and returns _createStampInFromOfficeWidget(); if data is fetched, but I still get the error caught here
error: (error, stack) {
developer.log('Error: $error');
return const ErrorText(errorText: 'Couldn't retrieve data');
}
So it seems there must be no changes to to the auth state, except when I turn the app off then on again

ahan ! but it worked in my case
whatever best of luck buddy

Gotta ask, but listening to auth state changes only listens to the users sign in state. whether the user is signed in or signed out. I'm able to log in and log out, but it's just that signing in a second time doesn't give me the right permission. So that might be as to why listening to auth state changes doesn't work

@RazerMackham, please update your question and include how the 'ref' field is created. I need to see if the userID in the 'ref' field is nullable.

Now I've updated the question
